# CleverTapSDK module not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I am using various Swift and Objective-C libraries in my (Swift) project. My `Podfile` looks as follows:
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'SimpleAuth/Instagram'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Parse'
```

To have support for using both (Swift and Objective-C) libraries, I use `use_framework!` directive in `Podfile` to install and use them. If we use directive `use_framework!` for Objective-C libraries, we are not required to create any kind of `bridging-header.h` and we can use it directly by `import ModuleName`. I am having no issues with any of the above mentioned pods/frameworks while installing or using them.

But there is this one framework which is written in Objective-C and I install it by adding its entry in `Podfile` as `pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK'`. The installations goes well but when I try to `import CleverTapSDK` or `import CleverTap` to use the library, it is giving me `no such module` error.

Just in case: My Xcode version is - 7.3 (7D175)